# How to open Google Play Games from an Activity?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm implementing my own view for leaderboards with Google Play Games and I show to the user a button when the profile is not public in order the user has quick link to google play games profile app, similar to what Google Leaderboard intent is doing. 
1-How can I launch Google Games from my activity?
2-Is it possible to open specific activity into Google Games App, like Player Profile?
Thanks in advance.